# Is there an out of directory project builder for PHP yet?

Tags: php, builder

So that I can keep the `.proj` from my PHP project.

This gives great flexibility for me to switch from one IDE to another(for debug,of course:)).

Comment: I dont understand your question. Do you mean you want your IDE to store the .proj file in a separate area from the source files themselves? If so pretty much all IDEs will give you that option when you create the project.

More details required.

Comment: In fact my problem is that I don't have a `.proj` file so ZendStudio can't import the project.So I'm seeking of a tool that can create out of directory `.proj` files,for ZendStudio, or for eclipse,at my disposal.

Comment: can you please explain your question bit brief?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no utility that creates 'project' files for the applications you mention.

You could try to open up a project file and if it is human readable you could have a go at creating the utility yourself.